# SELECT GROUP BY latest entry in INBOX msg sent by user

Tags: php, mysql

i am building a simple PM for my personal website where a user can join and send message to the registered users on my website,

i am stuck in grouping and selecting latest user (by latest msg time)  in INBOX page

my table :

```
id   msg_from   msg_to  msg   date   in_del   out_del
```

i want to show latest user's id each in a group

here is my SQL query :

```
SELECT ttalk.id, ttalk.msg_from,  users.first_name, users.last_name
FROM ttalk
INNER JOIN users ON ttalk.msg_from = users.id 
WHERE ttalk.msg_to = '$_SESSION[user_id]' AND ttalk.in_del='0'
GROUP BY ttalk.msg_from DESC LIMIT 500
```

FOR EXAMPLE : in facebook when a old friend send msg then his/her thread goes on top

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be `ORDER BY` with `DATE` like

```
GROUP BY ttalk.msg_from ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 500
```

Secondary You can also `ORDER BY` with `id` if it is an auto increment but not much suggestable when you are having the `DATE` field.

Comment: its working but when the same user sent msg again then its not going on top

Comment: Is it so..??It will work Bec we are Grouping with msg_from and date in  descending order...

Comment: See this WHERE ttalk.msg_to = '$_SESSION[user_id]' you need to change this to msg_from at your case

Comment: FOR EXAMPLE : in facebook when a old friend send msg then his/her thread goes on top

Comment: for that I have stated the first and that with date descending order.Bec its date will be the recent sent date.So it will come top